# AMD Vega M stopped being detected by Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card, hp-spectre

I am using my HP Spectre-X360 15T laptop for a little over a year now and it was running fine until a couple days ago I discovered it stopped detecting my built-in RADEON RX VEGA M Graphics card. It is like it is suddenly totally missing from the build.

These are the system specs:
[System Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLN3i.jpg)

The driver settings used to show up under [right click options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K69df.png) but now it shows the Intel Graphics Settings instead of the RADEON Settings.

The display adapter is missing in [Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu46s.jpg) and also in [DirectX Diagnostic Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfiJd.jpg)

Similarly, it is missing in [Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e32wx.jpg) as well

I uninstalled the drivers and tried installing the related drivers from AMD website but they report that no compatible hardware was detected. I used the AMD Auto Detect Tool but it kept crashing.

I have no idea what has happened. Everything was fine just a few days ago. I have provided image links for better understanding. Feel free to ask for any other information.

Thanks! I hope this gets solved.

Comment: Check the BIOS settings. Try resetting to optimized defaults.

Comment: Tried but no change